# internal name of Default Task Status field on 2013 OnPrem?

Tags: task-list, spfield, internal-name

I don't have OnPrem at hand,

can someone check what the **internal** fieldname is for the default Tasks List "Task Status" field.

On Office365 it is Status,

[image]

I know it was **TaskStatus** in SharePoint 2010

Now wonder when the change was made.. (could have been an intermediate CU?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is where the confusion comes from:

[in List settings ContentTypes:]

In the **(List) Task** ContentType the "Task Status" internal name is **Status**

[select the source ContentType **Task**:]

In the **(Site) Task** ContentType the "Task Status" internal name is **TaskStatus**

Same internal field renaming (but why?) with:

- DueDate (List ContentType) => TaskDueDate (Site Column)

---

So when adding the DueDate Site Column to another List or Document Library, **TaskDueDate** has to be used as the CSR Internal name (and **DueDate** for the 'same' column in the standard Tasks List)

Answer (score 2):

I have a SP2013 OnPrem running and its showing Field=Status

I just checked with powershell, its like this:

```
StaticName                 Title                      InternalName
----------                 -----                      ------------
Status                     Task Status                Status
```

Comment: tnx, In another SO question someone says he is on 2013 and its TaskStatus.. I am beginning to fear it was a Cumulative Update change. For CSR usage it means 2 definitions are required

Comment: I have seen different values on SP2013 as well, but I suspect installation language. If the Server was installed in english the Title may differ from a german install. That's why I always install in english and later install language packs. - also german error names are hideous ;)

Answer (score 0):

The internal name of workflow tasks Status field is also **STATUS**

Please refer the image below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Internal field name for Task Status is **TaskStatus**

**SharePoint 2013 on-prem** --> vti_extenderversion:SR|**15.0.0.4641**

**office 365** --> MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices:**16.0.0.5312**

Internal field name for Task Status (office 365) is also **TaskStatus**